# DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found while importing scipy

Tags: python, scipy, importerror

I have installed python with Anaconda on windows 10. I have created a virtual environment with Anaconda called `venv`. After activating the environment, `>>>python` gives:

```
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Feb 11 2019, 15:03:47) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

I have installed `scipy` in my `venv` using pip: `pip install scipy`.

I have set the interpreter in pycharm to the `venv` python interpreter.

[image]

Now, I tried the following in a new module in pycharm:

```
import scipy    # No error here
from scipy.stats import norm # Here I got the error
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Documents/February2019/AVEC2018/ApplyPCA.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scipy.optimize import _hungarian
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py", line 386, in <module>
    from .optimize import *
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .linesearch import (line_search_wolfe1, line_search_wolfe2,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\linesearch.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scipy.optimize import minpack2
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have followed the instructions [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001722979-ImportError-DLL-load-failed-The-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found-) as an attempt to solve the problem.

Therefore, I ran `print(os.environ['PATH'])` while using the `venv` python interpreter in cmd (i.e., after activating `venv`); I copied the following result

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\venv;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\venv\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\venv\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\venv\Library\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\venv\Scripts;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\venv\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\libnvvp;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin;C:\Users\user\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\cuda7\cuda\bin;C:\Program Files\Weka-3-8;C:\Users\user\Downloads\ffmpeg-20170904-6cadbb1-win64-static\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\user\Downloads\pandoc-2.1.2;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64;C:\Users\user\Downloads\cmake-3.11.2-win64-x64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\extras\CUPTI\libx64;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\altera\13.0\modelsim_ase\win32aloem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs
```

and paste it in a new variable in **run/debug configuration** and in **python console** as:

[image]

[image]

But that didn't solve the problem. Please note that I tried installing `scipy` using `conda install scipy`, and the problem wasn't solved. Finally, the problem doesn't arise while working from cmd, but do exist when working from python console (inside pycharm) and pycharm.

I found out that running `print(os.environ['PATH'])` within the python console inside pycharm gave me the following:

```
C:\Users\iayou005\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\venv\Library\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\libnvvp;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin;C:\Users\iayou005\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\cuda7\cuda\bin;C:\Program Files\Weka-3-8;C:\Users\iayou005\Downloads\ffmpeg-20170904-6cadbb1-win64-static\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\iayou005\Downloads\pandoc-2.1.2;C:\Users\iayou005\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\iayou005\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\iayou005\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64;C:\Users\iayou005\Downloads\cmake-3.11.2-win64-x64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\extras\CUPTI\libx64;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI;C:\Users\iayou005\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\altera\13.0\modelsim_ase\win32aloem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\iayou005\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;
```

Therefore, the following 2 paths are missing:

```
C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/venv;C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/venv/Scripts;
```

I have no idea how to fix this given all the attempts mentioned above

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: PyCharmm has a "environment setting". Make sure that you have not *only* selected the executable from the environment but the actual conda environment. PyCharmm, as I understand it, understands the requirements of conda environments if properly set up.

Comment: Also, your environment is called `venv`, is that the case? This is extremely confusing, please name it according to a specific need as this makes reading your error logs difficult. Examples: "default-env", just "default" would already be better than "venv". "project1", "py36", etc.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl, thank you for your comments, but yea, unfortunately I have chosen `venv` as my virtual environment name. As for the chosen interpreter, I have chosen the existing one specified for my `venv`, its path: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\venv`. Hope this helps!!

Comment: I use linux, so not all may apply. When setting up an interpreter, there is a category "conda environment". The settings are "conda executable" (the full path to the "conda" program) and location (the location of the environment). You should use that and remove all the custom environment variables.

Comment: HELLO @I.A, I also got the same issue. May I know where did you command ```print(os.environ['PATH'])``` in pycharm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have misplaced the name of the environment variable and its value in the configuration dialog.

It should be `PATH=list_of_paths`, not `list_of_paths=PATH`