# Pycharm doesnt import osmosdr to my .py file

Tags: python, pycharm, importerror, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have install gnuradio 3.7 in windows 10, and the gnu radio import works fine in pycharm after adding: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages, to the path.

But the problem it´s when i try to import *osmosdr*.
[image]

Do im missing a path,? or i dont have the neccesary ddl´s´file?.

NOTE: Running the block.py in gnu radio, works fine, the issue is when i tried to compile in pycharm.

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54971114/dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-while-importing-scipy  and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001722979-ImportError-DLL-load-failed-The-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found-

Comment: The issue was that i was acturally missing some paths, so to start clean in a new proyect, with the default installation, the next paths work for me:

Comment: PYTHONHOME=C:\Program Files\GNURadio-3.7\gr-python27|

Comment: PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files\GNURadio-3.7\gr-python27\Lib\site-packages;

C:\Program Files\GNURadio-3.7\gr-python27\dlls;

C:\Program Files\GNURadio-3.7\gr-python27\libs;

C:\Program Files\GNURadio-3.7\gr-python27\lib;

C:\Program Files\GNURadio-3.7\lib\site-packages;

C:\Program Files\GNURadio-3.7\gr-python27\Lib\site-packages\pkgconfig;

Comment: But now i got this issue:

Comment: File "D:\Modular\CODIGOV2\venv\lib\site.py", line 769, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Modular\CODIGOV2\venv\lib\site.py", line 757, in main
    aliasmbcs()
  File "D:\Modular\CODIGOV2\venv\lib\site.py", line 515, in aliasmbcs
    enc = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getdefaultlocale'